# Mule load property value from flow Variable

Tags: mule

I have a scenario where i need to get the value from the property file and the values which i need to get will be from a variable.

**My props File**

```
org1 =active
org1_oracle_user = blah
org1_oracle_password = blahblah
org2 =active
org2_oracle_user = blah2
org2_oracle_password = blah2blah2
org3 = Active
org3_oracle_user = blah3
org3_oracle_password = blah3blah3
```

Now i'm getting the value of the org through some input and i was able to save into some variable.

```
<set-variable variableName="org_name" value="org1" doc:name="OrgNameVariable" />
```

Also i'm able to get the status of that org as active or not through dataweave

```
<set-variable variableName="orgTypeStatus" value="#[dw('p(flowVars.org_name)')]" doc:name="orgTypeStatusVariable" />
```

I was able to retrieve the value as active or not

But now how do I append the other key values to flow variable org_name
to get thier user and password

```
 <set-variable variableName="m_user" value="#[dw('p(flowVars.org_name.concat('_oracle_user'))')]" doc:name="user"/>
```

The above code is not working it says execution of expression fails.

I have give a sample example as there are other props based on the org name and I cant hard code it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this expression:-

```
#[dw('p(flowVars.org_name ++ "_oracle_user")')]
```

So, you need to escape `""` in the expression and so your variable in XML config will be as follows:-

```
<set-variable variableName="m_user" value="#[dw('p(flowVars.org_name ++ &quot;_oracle_user&quot;)')]" doc:name="user"/>
```

Comment: How do I get the value without dataweave??

Comment: you need to use spring to load your properties file and use app.registy to get the properties value. there you can concatenate the string... refer:- https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/62940/dynamic-access-to-properties-file-based-on-flowvar.html#answer-62943