# Mule load property value from flow Variable without datawave

Tags: mule

I have a scenario where i need to get the value from the property file and the values which i need to get will be from a variable.

**My props File**

```
org1 =active
org1_oracle_user = blah
org1_oracle_password = blahblah
org2 =active
org2_oracle_user = blah2
org2_oracle_password = blah2blah2
org3 = Active
org3_oracle_user = blah3
org3_oracle_password = blah3blah3
```

Now i'm getting the value of the org through some input and i was able to save into some variable.

Now how do I get the value from the propertyfile using a flowvariable without dataweave.
I know how to get the value through dataweave as follows

```
<set-variable variableName="orgTypeStatus" value="#[dw('p(flowVars.org_name)')]" doc:name="orgTypeStatusVariable" />
```

But unable to know how to get the value without dataweave.

I have give a sample example as there are other props based on the org name and I cant hard code it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if you need to pick the value from properties file you can use `${}` something like the following :-

```
<logger level="INFO" message="${org1}" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

But based on your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43944539/mule-load-property-value-from-flow-variable/43945798?noredirect=1#comment75039588_43945798), I can see you want to try this without using dataweave.
So, to ake it dynamic and pick the properties value dynamically, you need to load your properties file using spring:-

```
 <spring:beans>
         <spring:bean id="appProps" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
             <spring:property name="singleton" value="true"/>
             <spring:property name="location" value="classpath:dev.properties"/>
         </spring:bean>
     </spring:beans>
```

Now, in the flow, you can try following dynamically:

```
<logger level="INFO" message="${org1}" doc:name="Logger"/>
<set-variable variableName="org_name" value="org1" doc:name="OrgNameVariable" />
<set-variable variableName="orgTypeStatus" value="#[app.registry.appProps[flowVars.org_name]]" doc:name="orgTypeStatusVariable" />
<set-variable variableName="m_user" value="#[app.registry.appProps[flowVars.org_name +'_oracle_user']]" doc:name="user"/>
<logger message="Logging variables:- m_user: #[flowVars.m_user] orgTypeStatus: #[flowVars.orgTypeStatus]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
```

Comment: It says Execution of the expression "app.registry.appProps[flowVars.org_name]" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException).

Comment: Its working now!! Forgot to use spring bean property loader instead using old context loader... After changing the prop to spring bean its working